# How can I remove the incomplete parenthesis without affect other row using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I have a data frame where I want to remove the parentheses and the string without affecting other row.

Assume the following dataframe "cusomter" with the column "Name"

```
Name
Company ABC (Malaysia) Ltd
Company HIJ (M) Ltd (B12
Company KLM (M) Ltd (
```

My code:

```
customer["Name"] = customer["Name"].str.replace(r"\([^()]{1,3}", "", regex=True)
```

Output:

```
Name
Company ABC aysia) Ltd
Company HIJ (M) Ltd
Company KLM (M) Ltd
```

My desire output:

```
Name
Company ABC (Malaysia) Ltd
Company HIJ (M) Ltd
Company KLM (M) Ltd
```

May I know if is it possible to do it? I had tried different codes and I'm still not able to get my desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there won't be nested parentheses in the garbage section, you can anchor the replacement to the end of the string.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"company": ["Company ABC (Malaysia) Ltd", "Company HIJ (M) Ltd (B12", "Company KLM (M) Ltd ("]})

df["company"] = df["company"].str.replace(r"\s*\([^()]*?$", "", regex=True)

print(df)
```

```
                      company
0  Company ABC (Malaysia) Ltd
1         Company HIJ (M) Ltd
2         Company KLM (M) Ltd
```